# XAML Button Causing Xamarin App to Crash on Startup

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I ma working on a cross platform app with Xamarin.Forms. I have a XAMl structure on my page as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HeartRateMonitor;assembly=HeartRateMonitor"
         x:Class="HeartRateMonitor.Pages.StartPage"
         Title="Start Page">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          //more row defs
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label  Text="Percentage Fill:"
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

     //Some other Items

    <Button x:Name="NewDeviceButton" Icon="glyphish_31_circle_x.png" 
            Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" /> //Causes app to crash

  </Grid>
```

When I run this and deploy my app to an iPhone, the app crashes on startup. However, when I comment out the Button Object in the code, it deploys and runs fine.

What is wrong with that line and why is it causing the whole app to crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Xamarin Forms [Button](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Button/) does not have an Icon property.  Use Image instead.

```
<Button x:Name="NewDeviceButton" Image="glyphish_31_circle_x.png" 
            Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" />
```